# Emacs: 'Find file' without changing working directory

Tags: emacs, elisp

My c/c++ projects tend to have fairly straightforward directory structures which separate out src, include, bin, etc. I also tend to have a master makefile in the uppermost directory. When working like this in Emacs, I always have to issue <kbd>M-x cd uppermost-dir</kbd> in order for my compilation shortcuts to work as expected.

Is there a way to keep the current directory the same as the one from which I launch Emacs? That is, can I stop Emacs from changing it's working directory when I open a file?

Alternatively, is there something crucial I'm missing about the typical workflow with a directory hierarchiy like this exclusively in Emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you can do this:

Make a file in the root directory of your project call `.dir-locals.el`

This will be read whenever you open a file in the directory or it's sub-directories.

In order to back up to the root folder and run make as your compile command, just put this in the `.dir-locals.el` file.

```
((nil . ((compile-command . "cd ~/mycode/c/; make"))))
```

`nil` is the mode to set local variables for (nil means any), so to do this for only C++ mode you could do this instead ...

```
((c++-mode . ((compile-command . "cd ~/mycode/c/; make"))))
```

Obviously you can set up a list with more options, say running ant for java files and so on.

[emacs manual entry for directory locals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Directory-Variables.html)

Answer (score 5):

Invoke `make` with the `--directory` argument to force it to change to that directory before doing anything:

`make --directory /path/to/your/project`

Comment: This works, too, but is ever so slightly more work than the .dir-locals.el solution described by Justin above. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make much difference but you could combine both ... ((nil . ((compile-command . "make --directory ~/mycode/c/")))) ... but I didn't test this

Answer (score 4):

Change to the project directory (where the *Makefile* is located) and call compile:

```
(defun my-compile ()
  (interactive)
  (when-let (default-directory (locate-dominating-file default-directory "Makefile"))
    (call-interactively 'compile)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The current directory associated with a buffer that's associated with a file is normally the directory containing the file. You can change it, but it's not necessary for what you want to do.

Set the variable `compilation-directory` through a file-local variable (typically relative to the current file, e.g. `"../.."`) or through `.dir-locals.el`.

Answer (score 1):

I used to `M-x compile <RET> cd /path/to/project && make -j8` but prefer the method by Ben nowadays.