# Define default compile command in Emacs

Tags: emacs, compilation

I have a project that uses a bash script to invoke `cmake` and `make`. I have successfully used this script from Emacs by using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile`, followed by typing:

```
cd ../..; ./build.sh
```

in the minibuffer. (The project organization is `top/src/various_source_folders` and `build.sh` is in `top/`.)

I am trying to define a [directory variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html) to specify the default command to use for `compile`. I have tried the following (both with single or double quotes around the compile command) in `.dir-locals.el`:

```
((c++-mode
 (compile-command 'cd ../..\; ./build.sh')))
```

Which gives no errors, but <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compile` still defaults to `make -k`.

```
((c++-mode
  (set-variable 'compile-command' "cd ../../\; ./build.sh")))
```

Which gives a warning about unsafe variables. Even if I choose apply, `compile` still defaults to `make -k`

Simply using <kbd>M-x</kbd> `eval-buffer` with the second line (`(set variable`...) in *scratch* correctly sets the compile command.

Is there a different way I can/should be doing this?

Comment: Hi are you using single quotes while setting the compile command or is that a typo?

Comment: The first code snippet is exactly what I type at a terminal or in the minibuffer. The second code snippet is exactly what I put in .dir-locals.el. Should I be using something else?

Comment: Single quotes stand for something else in lisp languages, try using double quotes for string. Something like `((c++-mode
 (compile-command "cd ../..\; ./build.sh")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367743/emacs-find-file-without-changing-working-directory/6368297#6368297).

Two periods and some parenthesis were missing from the syntax:

```
((c++-mode
  . ((compile-command . "cd ../../\; ./build.sh"))))
```